# Memory corruption with libtorrent-rasterbar and QGuiApplication

Tags: qt, libtorrent

I'm trying to use libtorrent in my Qt5 application but keep getting segfaults
with messages like malloc(): memory corruption. After hours of debbuging I come up with this small piece of code which triggers this problem:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    std::string filename = "fedora.torrent";
    libtorrent::error_code ec;
    libtorrent::add_torrent_params parameters;
    std::cerr << "111\n";
    parameters.ti = new libtorrent::torrent_info(filename, ec);;
    std::cerr << "222\n";
    return app.exec()
}
```

In this case constructor of torrent_info produce segfault. But if I move libtorrent related code before creation of QGuiApplication like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string filename = "fedora.torrent";
    libtorrent::error_code ec;
    libtorrent::add_torrent_params parameters;
    std::cerr << "111\n";
    parameters.ti = new libtorrent::torrent_info(filename, ec);;
    std::cerr << "222\n";
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    return app.exec()
}
```

then it works just fine. Also this problem exist only in 32-bit build, in 64-bit build both variants work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by building libtorrent with one set of `TORRENT_`* defines and linking against it with a different set. Some of those defines affect layouts of some structs used in the public API and when differing between the calling application and the library introduce ABI incompatibility issues.

Comment: Thank you. After using libtorrent build cfalgs from pkg-config in my CMakeLists.txt problem was solved.