# QGuiApplication corrupts unrelated code

Tags: qt, vtk

I'm facing a similar problem as described in [Memory corruption with libtorrent-rasterbar and QGuiApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20178064/memory-corruption-with-libtorrent-rasterbar-and-qguiapplication).

In my case a vtk-reader (`vtkPDBReader`) returns wrong values when called after `QGuiApplication app(argc, argv)`. The program is running on a 64-bit Ubuntu system.

The answer in the related question does not help me. As far as I understand, the `QGuiApplication` somehow changes the way the system executes some other functions, but I don't know how to apply this to my problem.
Can anyone give a more general answer on how to fix this?
I built VTK with the shared_libs option and linking is done via cmake.

Thank you.

Here's a minimal Example:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES *.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADER *.h)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
        include_directories(${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

add_executable(test ${SOURCES} ${HEADER})

target_link_libraries(
    test
    ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
    ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES}
)
```

main.cpp

```
#include "qguiapplication.h"
#include "vtkPDBReader.h"
#include "vtkSmartPointer.h"
#include "vtkPolyData.h"
#include "vtkPointData.h"
#include "vtkPoints.h"

void load(){
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPDBReader> pdb =
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkPDBReader>::New();
    std::string molFile = "PDBfile.pdb";
    pdb->SetFileName(molFile.c_str());
    pdb->Update();

    // prepare a vector that will contain xyz
    std::vector<float> atomPositions;
    atomPositions.clear();

    for(vtkIdType i = 0; i < pdb->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfPoints(); i++)
    {
        double p[3];
        p[0] = 0;
        p[1] = 0;
        p[2] = 0;
        pdb->GetOutput()->GetPoint(i, p);
        atomPositions.push_back(p[0]);
        atomPositions.push_back(p[1]);
        atomPositions.push_back(p[2]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    load(); // works fine
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    load(); // read data is corrupt
}
```

The first call of `load()` works as expected. For the second call, after `QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);`,  `p[0]` contains the expected value cast to an integer, `p[1]` is always set to 4.59163e-41 and `p[2]` is always 0.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it in your question.

Comment: It sounds like Heap corruption to me... That is one of the few ways that introduction of unrelated code can change behavior in other parts of the program.  Make sure you are accessing variables that have been initialized, and zero out memory that gets deleted.  And then before the first access of a variable, make sure it is non zero.

Comment: If you are on Windows, it's the typical binary incompatibility hell you get when you use pre-built stuff. You have to build Qt, VTK and your code yourself, with the same version of Visual Studio. On Unix, you must be using them all built by the same repository, or, again, you should rebuild them all from sources.